# NativeScript Android API Version check

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I added android platform to my nativescript app using the following command

`tns platform add android`

Now I cannot figure out which API version of the platform was added?

How can I figure this out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `platform add android` command will fetch all necessary files to start building apps for Android. I'll assume that you are asking about the compileSdk version of android apps - that is determined at *Build* time.

When you execute `tns build/run android` unless the `--compileSdk 21/22/23/24/25` flag is specified, the latest version available on your system will be used.

So for example if I just recently downloaded Android SDK Build-Tools and SDK-Platform 25 from the Android SDK Manager the application package that is uploaded on the device will be built with platform 25.

Medium have a good article about compileSdk, targetSdk and minSdk that I recommend you read -> https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.eoe0x9isx

Good luck!

Comment: I am unaware of native Android development..But I am asking about API version meaning I want to build my app for API 19 i.e, Android 4.4 ..Does Nativescript have a Config.xml file like in cordova

Comment: You can freely build Android Apps for Android devices running on API Level as low as 17, and you can build the packages with compileSdk as low as 21. For example you can deploy an app on a phone API 19 even when you build the package with Build-tools 25.



Now, it is the developer's responsibility to handle differences in API levels accordingly, but that should not be necessary in 99% of the cases when writing NativeScript. The core-modules that are available with every NativeScript application have already taken care of that, and you may only have to consume those to write your next app.

Comment: Correct me If I am Not wrong..I can build apps without having to worry about the API level as is the case with cordova

Comment: @krv correct, and if in doubt, you can check in the Android docs whether the functionality you want to use is available for the level of the target device!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the resource. However, I'm in a situation where I need to check the android version at run-time a.i. if(VERSION>xx). How would you go about it - if it's even possible? Google didn't help on this one...

Comment: @radu_m checking the Android version can be done just like you would in Android - `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){ ... }` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html is where you find all version codes.

Answer (score 1):

latest docs say:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/platform

```
import { isAndroid, isIOS, device, screen } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
class DeviceInfo {
    constructor(
        public model: string,
        public deviceType: string,
        public os: string,
        public osVersion: string,
        public sdkVersion: string,
        public language: string,
        public manufacturer: string,
        public uuid: string
    ) { }
}

class ScreenInfo {
    constructor(
        public heightDIPs: number,
        public heightPixels: number,
        public scale: number,
        public widthDIPs: number,
        public widthPixels: number
    ) { }
}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./platform-module-example.html"
})
export class PlatformModuleExampleComponent {
    public isItemVisible: boolean = false;
    public deviceInformation: DeviceInfo;
    public isItemVisibleScreenInfo: boolean = false;
    public screenInformation: ScreenInfo;
    public deviceInfoButton: string = "Show device info";
    public screenInfoButton: string = "Show/Hide screen info";

    constructor() {
        this.deviceInformation = new DeviceInfo(
            device.model,
            device.deviceType,
            device.os,
            device.osVersion,
            device.sdkVersion,
            device.language,
            device.manufacturer,
            device.uuid);
        this.screenInformation = new ScreenInfo(
            screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs,
            screen.mainScreen.heightPixels,
            screen.mainScreen.scale,
            screen.mainScreen.widthDIPs,
            screen.mainScreen.widthPixels);
    }

    public checkPlatformType(args) {
        let message = "";
        if (isAndroid) {
            message = "You are using Android device";
        } else if (isIOS) {
            message = "You are using IOS device";
        }
        alert(message);
    }

    public deviceInfo(args) {
        if (this.isItemVisible) {
            this.isItemVisible = false;
            this.deviceInfoButton = "Show device info";
        } else {
            this.isItemVisible = true;
            this.deviceInfoButton = "Hide device info";
        }
    }

    public screenInfo(args) {
        if (this.isItemVisibleScreenInfo) {
            this.isItemVisibleScreenInfo = false;
            this.screenInfoButton = "Show screen info";
        } else {
            this.isItemVisibleScreenInfo = true;
            this.screenInfoButton = "Hide screen info";
        }
    }
}
```